# Windows Phone - LongListSelector grouped items by date and ordered by date

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, longlistselector

I have my `BaseArticle` class which has `PublishedDate` and I would like to group items by days and after that I would like to order them by date and time. For now I can group them by day and it works (I created get property `PublishedDateString` which returns date in string):

```
    public List<Group<BaseArticle>> GetArticlesGroups()
    {
        return GetItemGroups<BaseArticle>(Articles, a => a.PublishedDateString);
    }

    private static List<Group<T>> GetItemGroups<T>(IEnumerable<T> itemList, Func<T, string> getKeyFunc)
    {
        IEnumerable<Group<T>> groupList = from item in itemList
                                          group item by getKeyFunc(item) into g
                                          orderby g.Key
                                          select new Group<T>(g.Key, g);

        return groupList.ToList();
    }
```

I am newbie in LINQ and I don't know how can I edit my `GetItemGroups` method to order items by date after their grouped. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just missing another `orderby` statement.

I don't have the complete `BaseArticle` class, so I just going to make this very simple by creating a Song/Artist class like so:

```C#
public class sample_model
{
    public sample_model(string artist, string song, string extra = "")
    {
        this.Artist = artist;
        this.Song = song;
        this.Extra = extra;
    }

    public string Artist { get; set; }
    public string Song { get; set; }
    public string Extra { get; set; }       
}
```

Then we going to make a list of the sample_model by doing this

```C#
private ObservableCollection<sample_model> CreateData()
{       
    ObservableCollection<sample_model> my_list = new ObservableCollection<sample_model>();
    my_list.Add(new sample_model("Faith + 1", "Body of Christ", "A Track"));
    my_list.Add(new sample_model("Faith + 1", "Christ Again", "A Track"));
    my_list.Add(new sample_model("Faith + 1", "A Night With the Lord", "A Track"));
    my_list.Add(new sample_model("Faith + 1", "Touch Me Jesus", "A Track"));
    my_list.Add(new sample_model("Faith + 1", "I Found Jesus (With Someone Else)", "A Track"));
    my_list.Add(new sample_model("Faith + 1", "Savior Self", "A Track"));
    my_list.Add(new sample_model("Faith + 1", "Christ What a Day", "A Track"));
    my_list.Add(new sample_model("Faith + 1", "Three Times My Savior", "A Track"));
    my_list.Add(new sample_model("Faith + 1", "Jesus Touched Me", "A Track"));
    my_list.Add(new sample_model("Faith + 1", "Lord is my Savior", "A Track"));
    my_list.Add(new sample_model("Faith + 1", "I Wasn't Born Again Yesterday", "A Track"));
    my_list.Add(new sample_model("Faith + 1", "Pleasing Jesus", "A Track"));
    my_list.Add(new sample_model("Faith + 1", "Jesus (Looks Kinda Hot)", "A Track"));
    my_list.Add(new sample_model("Butters", "What What", "B Track"));

    // add a duplicate song for our example
    my_list.Add(new sample_model("Faith + 1", "Body of Christ", "A Track"));

    return my_list;
}

// create our list
ObservableCollection<sample_model> DataSource = CreateData();
```

---

At this point we have 2 Artist (Faith + 1 and Butters).

We can query and group this List of data by Artist Name by doing this

```C#
var query = from item in DataSource
            group item by item.Artist into ArtistGroup
            orderby ArtistGroup.Key
            select ArtistGroup;

foreach (var ArtistGroup in query)
{
    // this will loop twice.  Once for Butters and Once for Faith + 1
    // it will order by Key which is the Artist Name
    // so Butters will be first then Faith + 1
    // but the Songs will not be ABC order, it will be order the same way we inserted them into the list
}
```

---

Now back to your original question! You want the list to be Sort by Artist and each Artist's Song to be Sorted as well.  Then you must have another `orderby statement`

```C#
// before we group by item.Artist, we sort by item.Song using another `orderby`      
var query = from item in svm.DataSource
            orderby item.Song
            group item by item.Artist into ArtistGroup
            orderby ArtistGroup.Key
            select ArtistGroup;

foreach (var ArtistGroup in query)
{
    // this will loop twice.  Once for Butters and Once for Faith + 1
    // it will order by Key which is the Artist Name
    // so Butters will be first then Faith + 1
    // this time the sub list of each Artist will have their Songs sorted as well

    // For example, under Faith + 1 you will see
    // "A Night With the Lord" follow by
    // "Body of Christ" (TWICE) remember we put 2 in 
}
```

Comment: It's working and it's okay. I first was thinking that I must to order it after it is grouped. Thanks for this :)